# Python json file generator add `][` between every 1000 elements

Tags: python, json

Below I have a function I've created that randomly generates `n` number of json objects. It then groups them in groups of 1000 and writes them to a file. The issue I've run into is that each time it writes a group of 1000 it add `][` between them making the json invalid. I'm fairly new to python and have tried looping over each element and doing a `.replace('][', ',')` but that isn't working. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import random
import json as json
import sys
import gzip
import common.common_functions as common

def get_args(p_args):
    if "--num-records" in p_args:
        num_records = int(p_args[int(p_args.index('--num-records'))+1])
    else:
        print("number of records defaulting to 1000")
        num_records = 1000

    if "--num-groups" in p_args:
        num_groups = int(p_args[int(p_args.index('--num-groups'))+1])
    else:
        print("number of groups defaulting to 10")
        num_groups = 10

    if "--compress" in p_args:
        compression = True
    else:
        compression = False

    if "--file-name" in p_args:
        file_name = p_args[int(p_args.index('--file-name'))+1]
    else:
        print("file_name param must be submitted")
        exit(-1)

    return num_records, num_groups, file_name, compression


def main():

    num_records, num_groups, file_name, compression = get_args(sys.argv)

    if compression:
        write_mode = 'wt'
    else:
        write_mode = 'w'

    state, min_zip, max_zip = common.pick_state()

    groups = common.generate_groups(num_groups)

    fnames, lnames, mnames, dobs, zips, genders,  group_ids, coverages = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

    for record_num in (num + 1 for num in range(num_records)):

        fnames.append(common.pick_fname())
        mnames.append(common.gen_mi())
        lnames.append(common.pick_lname())
        dobs.append(common.gen_date_in_range("1925/01/01","2000/12/31","%Y/%m/%d","%Y/%m/%d"))
        zips.append(common.gen_zip(min_zip, max_zip))
        genders.append(common.gen_gender())
        group_ids.append(common.pick_group(groups))
        coverages.append(random.randint(1000,500000))

        sample_records = [{"fname": fname, "mname": mname, "lname": lname, "dob:": dob, "zip": zip, "gender": gender, "group_id": group_id, "coverage": coverage} \
                          for fname, mname, lname, dob, zip, gender, group_id, coverage in zip(fnames,mnames,lnames,dobs,zips,genders,group_ids,coverages)]

        if (record_num % 1000 == 0):
            if compression:
                with gzip.open(file_name, write_mode, encoding='ascii') as zipfile:
                    json.dump(sample_records, zipfile)
                if write_mode == 'wt':
                    write_mod = 'at'
            else:
                with open(file_name, write_mode) as json_file:
                    json.dump(sample_records, json_file)
                if write_mode == 'w':
                    write_mode = 'a'

            fnames, lnames, mnames, dobs, zips, genders,  group_ids, coverages = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

            print (record_num)

    if compression:
        with gzip.open(file_name, write_mode, encoding='ascii') as zipfile:
            json.dump(sample_records, zipfile)
    else:
         with open(file_name, write_mode) as json_file:
            json.dump(sample_records, json_file)


main()
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
{
    "fname": "JAMES",
    "mname": "W",
    "lname": "KIRVIN",
    "dob:": "1937/04/25",
    "zip": "43650",
    "gender": "F",
    "group_id": "p28m80z8",
    "coverage": 264200
}, {
    "fname": "JUSTIN",
    "mname": "P",
    "lname": "REUTEBUCH",
    "dob:": "1941/02/09",
    "zip": "44254",
    "gender": "M",
    "group_id": "6x6olrgc",
    "coverage": 251417
}][{ <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Here is the issue
    "fname": "EMILY",
    "mname": "U",
    "lname": "STEEDLE",
    "dob:": "1948/12/30",
    "zip": "44524",
    "gender": "M",
    "group_id": "6x7d4c43",
    "coverage": 25278
}, {
```

Ideally I would like the out put json that is saved to be valid

Comment: What do you want instead?

Comment: I believe to replace the `][` with `,`

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky How would that help? It's still not valid JSON, it would need `[...]` around the whole thing.

Comment: If you would like the output to be valid JSON, put everything in a single list and then save it all at once.

Comment: Take your list, break it into a list of 1000-element lists, then dump *that* as a single JSON value.

Comment: Yes, but I believe the question addresses how to deal with the `][` situation, maybe the OP has this other aspect covered.

Comment: I would like for each time I write a group of 1000 rows to a file that it not add the ][ between them so that the json is valid.

Comment: And take a look at the `argparse` package instead of writing your own command-line argument parser.

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky The question said he tried replacing `][` with `],[`.

Comment: @Barmar I would like the json file I write out to be valid. Currently it is adding ][ in between each 1000 rows I dump. I'm not exactly sure why it's add them either or how to remove them.

Comment: What about `.replace("}][{", "}, {")`?

Comment: It's not adding anything. JSON for a list begins with `[` and ends with `]`. `][` is the end of one list followed by the beginning of the next one.

Comment: You should create a 2-dimensional list, and then write the entire thing with one call to `json.dump()` at the end.

Comment: @Barmar Okay thank you I'll try that.

Comment: Does the list not fit into memory? RAM is quiet cheap those days. Just keep the list growing and always write the whole file. With a list of list, you willl run into a similar issue I'd guess. If you still want to append, look into CSV, your data sems to be simple enough

Comment: @PeterSchneider Yeah that has been an issue I'm using this script to generate files with 10 - 15 million rows in them.

Comment: @PeterSchneider This data is used for a data ingestion pipeline that is expecting json format otherwise I would.

Comment: If it doesn't fit into memory when creating the file, you'll run into the same problem when reading it.

Comment: Maybe try to dump object by object and do the `, ` in between manually. If you find an empty file, start with `[`. At the end, close with `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this:

- dump the list into a temporary json-string
- for all but the first batch: remove the leading `[`
- for all: remove the trailing `]`
- before writing all but the first batch, write a `,` to file before the manipulated json-string

This should produce valid json. Based on your code:

```
import random
import json as json
import sys
import gzip
import common.common_functions as common

def get_args(p_args):
    if "--num-records" in p_args:
        num_records = int(p_args[int(p_args.index('--num-records'))+1])
    else:
        print("number of records defaulting to 1000")
        num_records = 1000

    if "--num-groups" in p_args:
        num_groups = int(p_args[int(p_args.index('--num-groups'))+1])
    else:
        print("number of groups defaulting to 10")
        num_groups = 10

    if "--compress" in p_args:
        compression = True
    else:
        compression = False

    if "--file-name" in p_args:
        file_name = p_args[int(p_args.index('--file-name'))+1]
    else:
        print("file_name param must be submitted")
        exit(-1)

    return num_records, num_groups, file_name, compression


def main():

    num_records, num_groups, file_name, compression = get_args(sys.argv)

    if compression:
        write_mode = 'wt'
    else:
        write_mode = 'w'

    state, min_zip, max_zip = common.pick_state()

    groups = common.generate_groups(num_groups)

    fnames, lnames, mnames, dobs, zips, genders,  group_ids, coverages = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

    for record_num in (num + 1 for num in range(num_records)):

        fnames.append(common.pick_fname())
        mnames.append(common.gen_mi())
        lnames.append(common.pick_lname())
        dobs.append(common.gen_date_in_range("1925/01/01","2000/12/31","%Y/%m/%d","%Y/%m/%d"))
        zips.append(common.gen_zip(min_zip, max_zip))
        genders.append(common.gen_gender())
        group_ids.append(common.pick_group(groups))
        coverages.append(random.randint(1000,500000))

        sample_records = [{"fname": fname, "mname": mname, "lname": lname, "dob:": dob, "zip": zip, "gender": gender, "group_id": group_id, "coverage": coverage} \
                          for fname, mname, lname, dob, zip, gender, group_id, coverage in zip(fnames,mnames,lnames,dobs,zips,genders,group_ids,coverages)]

        if (record_num % 1000 == 0):
            text = json.dumps(sample_records)
            text = text[:-1] # remove trailing ]
            if write_mode[0] == 'a':
                text = text[1:] # remove leading [
            if compression:
                with gzip.open(file_name, write_mode, encoding='ascii') as zipfile:
                    if write_mode[0] == 'a':
                        zipfile.write(',')
                    zipfile.write(text)
                if write_mode == 'wt':
                    write_mode = 'at'
            else:
                with open(file_name, write_mode) as json_file:
                    if write_mode[0] == 'a':
                        json_file.write(',')
                    json_file.write(text)
                if write_mode == 'w':
                    write_mode = 'a'

            fnames, lnames, mnames, dobs, zips, genders,  group_ids, coverages = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

            print (record_num)

    if sample_records:
        text = json.dumps(sample_records)
        text = text[:-1] # remove trailing ]
        if write_mode[0] == 'a':
            text = text[1:] # remove leading [

        if compression:
            with gzip.open(file_name, write_mode, encoding='ascii') as zipfile:
                if write_mode[0] == 'a':
                    zipfile.write(',')
                zipfile.write(text)
        else:
            with open(file_name, write_mode) as json_file:
                if write_mode[0] == 'a':
                    json_file.write(',')
                json_file.write(text)


    # closing "]"
    if compression:
        with gzip.open(file_name, write_mode, encoding='ascii') as zipfile:
            zipfile.write(']')
    else:
        with open(file_name, write_mode) as json_file:
            json_file.write(']')

main()
```

(untested - I do not have `common.common_functions` ^^) Note that your code have some code smells. E.g. you repeat the code for uncompressed/ compressed writing multiple times. And you recreate `sample_records` every round. Just appending would be enough. Also look for `write_mode` vs `write_mod` (there was a typo in your version, should be fixed in mine).